# Django Rest not creating extended UserProfile

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-auth

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I've created an extended UserProfile model as follows:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #Some Fields for UserProfile

    def user_profile_url(self):
        return reverse('user_profile', args=(self.user.id, "{}-{}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)))

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

However, on signing up using `rest_auth`'s `/registration` endpoint: http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_endpoints.html#registration, the UserProfile is not being created even though the `User` is created. In my `serializers.py`, I've done the following for users who sign up

```
class UserSignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(email=validated_data['email'], username=validated_data['email'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        profile.save()
        return user
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hi@Newtt Did you get solution? Please paste here if you got one.

Answer (score 0):

Because request goes here https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/views.py#L38 and doesn't call serializer.create() actually.

Try to override signup form as suggested in the docs:

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
   'signup': 'path.to.custom.SignupForm'
}
```

example of the profile form:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2081/

Comment: Using above form. It shows this error : RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form ProfileForm needs updating
  class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):